# These dependencies ware not found in vuejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, webpack

These dependencies were not found:

```
* -!../../../../node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--8-oneOf-1-1!../../../../node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!../../../../node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js??ref--8-oneOf-1-2!vuetify/dist/vuetify.css in ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--8-oneOf-1-1!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--8-oneOf-1-2!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--8-oneOf-1-3!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/view/pages/vuetify/Vuetify.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=scss&
* vuetify/lib/framework in ./src/core/plugins/vuetify.js

To install them, you can run: npm install --save -!../../../../node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--8-oneOf-1-1!../../../../node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!../../../../node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js??ref--8-oneOf-1-2!vuetify/dist/vuetify.css vuetify/lib/framework
```

this my package.js file

```
{
    "name": "metronic-vue-demo1",
    "version": "7.2.8",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
        "build": "vue-cli-service build",
        "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
        "rtl": "webpack --config webpack-rtl.config.js"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@babel/polyfill": "^7.4.4",
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.13.0",
        "@mdi/font": "^3.6.95",
        "@popperjs/core": "^2.4.0",
        "@riophae/vue-treeselect": "^0.4.0",
        "animate.css": "^4.1.0",
        "apexcharts": "^3.19.0",
        "axios": "^0.19.2",
        "axios-mock-adapter": "^1.18.1",
        "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
        "bootstrap-vue": "^2.13.0",
        "clipboard": "^2.0.6",
        "core-js": "^3.6.5",
        "deepmerge": "^4.2.2",
        "highlight.js": "^9.18.1",
        "line-awesome": "^1.3.0",
        "moment": "^2.29.1",
        "object-path": "^0.11.4",
        "perfect-scrollbar": "^1.5.0",
        "portal-vue": "^2.1.7",
        "roboto-fontface": "*",
        "socicon": "^3.0.5",
        "sweetalert2": "^9.10.12",
        "tooltip.js": "^1.3.2",
        "v-toaster": "^1.0.3",
        "vee-validate": "^3.4.9",
        "vue": "^2.6.11",
        "vue-apexcharts": "^1.5.3",
        "vue-axios": "^2.1.4",
        "vue-cropperjs": "^4.1.0",
        "vue-good-table": "^2.21.10",
        "vue-highlight.js": "^3.1.0",
        "vue-i18n": "^8.17.4",
        "vue-inline-svg": "^1.3.0",
        "vue-router": "^3.1.5",
        "vue-sweetalert2": "^4.3.1",
        "vue2-perfect-scrollbar": "^1.5.0",
        "vuelidate": "^0.7.5",
        "vuex": "^3.3.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^4.5.9",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^4.5.9",
        "@vue/cli-service": "^4.5.9",
        "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^4.0.1",
        "babel-eslint": "^10.0.3",
        "eslint": "^5.16.0",
        "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.3",
        "eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.0.0",
        "sass": "^1.29.0",
        "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
        "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "^2.0.5",
        "vue-loader": "^15.9.7",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.14",
        "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11",
        "webpack-messages": "^2.0.4",
        "webpack-rtl-plugin": "^2.0.0"
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
        "root": true,
        "env": {
            "node": true
        },
        "extends": [
            "plugin:vue/essential",
            "eslint:recommended"
        ],
        "rules": {
            "no-unused-vars": "off"
        },
        "parserOptions": {
            "parser": "babel-eslint"
        }
    },
    "browserslist": [
        "> 1%",
        "last 2 versions",
        "not ie <= 10"
    ]
}
```

how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

For me solve this

```
npm install vuetify-loader -D
npm cache clean --force
npm install vuetify
```